# JSF Primefaces 10: How to Enforce 4 digit year in Text Field & Display Error Message?

Tags: jsf, primefaces

Am using Java 1.8 and Primefaces 10... Am fairly new to JSF UI programming. Have a date text field, in which, end users can either type in the particular date and/or also use a calendar widget. However, when end users type in a date with a two digit year format, for example: `7/19/21` - its becomes rendered wrong after saving it inside the JSF xhtml form: `0021-07-17T08:00:00Z`. What I need is a way to enforce a 4 digit date (by providing an error message to the end user) and fix this from rendering incorrectly (need it to be `2021-07-17T08:00:00Z` instead of `0021-07-17T08:00:00Z`).

---

So, when entering it manually (and not using the calendar widget):

[image]

This is what it ends up rendering (incorrectly, after saving):

[image]

---

pom.xml:

```
<properties>
    <primefaces-version>10.0.0</primefaces-version>
    <primefaces-extension-version>10.0.1</primefaces-extension-version>
</properties>

 <dependency>
    <groupId>org.primefaces</groupId>
    <artifactId>primefaces</artifactId>
    <version>${primefaces-version}</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.primefaces.extensions</groupId>
    <artifactId>primefaces-extensions</artifactId>
    <version>${primefaces-extension-version}</version>
</dependency>
```

---

editForm.xhtml:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
        "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
      xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html" xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
      xmlns:input="http://www.mycompany.com/jsf/facelets"
>
<ui:composition>
<ui:define name="content"> 
    <h:form id="form">
       <p:growl/>
       <p:panel header="Form Information">
          <table>
                <tr>
                <td valign="top">
                    <p:panelGrid columns="3">
                    <input:input type="date"
                                 label="Start Date:"
                                 bean="#{MyView}"
                                 property="startDate"
                                 timeZone="#{MyView.timezone}"/>    
                    </p:panel>
                    </p:panelGrid></td>
                </tr>
          </table>
       </p:panel>
       <p:commandButton action="#{myView.save}"
     </h:form>
    </ui:define>
</ui:composition>
</html>
```

---

```
import java.util.Date;

import javax.annotation.Nullable;
import javax.annotation.PostConstruct;
import javax.faces.view.ViewScoped;
import javax.inject.Inject;
import javax.inject.Named;

import com.myapp.model.DomainObj;

@Named
@ViewScoped
public class MyView implements Serializable {

    private DomainObj   domain;
    private Date        startDate;
    private String      timezone;

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        startDate = new Date();
        if (domain == null) {
            timezone = "America/Los_Angeles";
        } else {
            // Please assume that domain is already instantiated. 
            if (domain.getStartDate() != null) {
                startDate =  Date.from(domain.getStartDate());
            }
        }
    }

    public String save() {
        domain.setTimezone(timezone);
        domain.setStartDate(startDate.toInstant());

    }
}
```

---

DomainObj.java:

```
package com.myapp.model;

import javax.persistence.Entity;

@Entity
@Table(name = "domain")
public class DomainObj {
    
    @Column(name = "start_date")
    private Instant startDate;

    @Column(name = "time_zone")
    private String timezone = "America/Los_Angeles";

    // Getters and Setters omitted for brevity reasons.

}
```

---

input.taglib.xml (custom taglib located inside `../src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/input.taglib.xml`):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<facelet-taglib version="2.2"
                xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
                xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
                xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-facelettaglibrary_2_2.xsd">
    <namespace>http://www.mycompany.com/jsf/facelets</namespace>
    <tag>
        <tag-name>input</tag-name>
        <source>tags/input.xhtml</source>
        <attribute>
            <description>
                Represents what the tag is for. For example, date.
            </description>
            <name>type</name>
            <required>true</required>
            <type>java.lang.String</type>
        </attribute>
    </tag>    

    <tag>
        <tag-name>show-errors</tag-name>
        <source>tags/show-errors.xhtml</source>
        <attribute>
            <name>errors</name>
            <required>true</required>
            <type>java.collections.Set</type>
        </attribute>
    </tag>
</facelet-taglib>
```

---

input.xhtml (custom taglib located inside `..src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/tags/input.xhtml`):

```
<ui:composition xmlns:c="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"
                xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
                xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
                xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
                xmlns:d="http://www.mycompany.com/jsf/facelets"
                xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets">

<c:set var="id" value="#{not empty id ? id : (not empty property ? property : action)}"/>
<c:set var="required" value="#{not empty required and required}"/>
<c:set var="size" value="#{not empty size ? size : 20}"/>
<c:set var="rendered" value="#{not empty rendered ? rendered : 'true'}"/>
<c:set var="maxLength" value="#{not empty maxLength ? maxLength : '300'}"/>
<c:set var="disabled" value="#{not empty disabled ? disabled : 'false'}"/>
<c:set var="placeholder" value="#{not empty placeholder ? placeholder : ''}"/>
<c:set var="labelStyle" value="#{not empty labelStyle ? labelStyle : ''}"/>
<c:set var="update" value="#{not empty update ? update : ''}"/>
<c:set var="oncomplete" value="#{not empty oncomplete ? oncomplete : ''}"/>

<c:choose>
        <c:when test="#{type == 'text'}">
            <c:choose>
                <!-- View Only -->
                <c:when test="#{viewOnly == 'true'}">
                    <h:outputText id="#{id}" value="#{bean[property]}"
                                  size='#{size}'
                                  style='#{style}'
                                  converter='#{converter}'
                                  rendered="#{rendered}">
                        <c:if test="#{not empty converter}">
                            <f:converter converterId="#{converter}"/>
                        </c:if>
                    </h:outputText>
                </c:when>

                <!-- Editable -->
                <c:when test="#{viewOnly == 'false'}">
                    <p:inputText id="#{id}" value="#{bean[property]}"
                                 label="#{label}"
                                 size="#{size}"
                                 style='#{style}'
                                 required="#{required}"
                                 disabled="#{disabled}"
                                 requiredMessage="#{requiredMessage}"
                                 maxlength="#{maxLength}"
                                 placeholder='#{placeholder}'
                                 rendered="#{rendered}">
                        <p:ajax event="blur" render="#{id}-message" update="#{update}"/>
                        <p:ajax event="change" update="#{update}" oncomplete="#{oncomplete}"/>
                        <c:if test="#{not empty converter}">
                            <f:converter converterId="#{converter}"/>
                        </c:if>
                    </p:inputText>
                </c:when>
            </c:choose>
        </c:when>

<c:when test="#{type == 'date'}">
    <c:choose>
        <c:when test="#{viewOnly == 'true'}">
            <h:outputText id="#{id}" value="#{bean[property]}" size="#{size}"
                          rendered="#{rendered}">
                <f:convertDateTime pattern="MM/dd/yyyy"/>
            </h:outputText>
        </c:when>
        <!-- Editable -->
        <c:when test="#{viewOnly == 'false'}">
            <p:calendar id="#{id}" value="#{bean[property]}" rendered="#{rendered}"
                        disabled="#{disabled}"
                        pattern="MM/dd/yyyy"
                        required="#{required}" requiredMessage="#{requiredMessage}" timeZone="#{timeZone}">
                <c:if test="#{not empty event}">
                    <p:ajax event="#{event}" update="#{update}"/>
                    <p:ajax event="dateSelect" update="#{update}" oncomplete="#{oncomplete}"/>
                </c:if>
            </p:calendar>
        </c:when>
    </c:choose>
</c:when>

<p:message id="#{id}-message" for="#{id}" rendered="#{rendered}"/>

</ui:composition>
```

---

show-errors.xhtml (custom taglib located inside `..src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/tags/show-errors.xhtml`):

```
<ui:composition xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
                xmlns:c="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"
                xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
                xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
                xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
                xmlns:d="http://www.mycompany.com/jsf/facelets"
                xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets">

    <ui:repeat value='#{errors}'  var='error'>
        <p  style='display:flex; margin: 10px 2px 10px 2px'>
            <span style='flex-grow: 1' class='error-code'>#{error.name()}</span>
            <span style='flex-grow:2'> : #{error.message}</span>
        </p>
    </ui:repeat>

</ui:composition>
```

---

Question(s):

- Where can I change it (Java code or one of the xhtml files listed above) so it enforces that an end user needs to have a 4 digit year format instead of the 2 digits?
- How can I display an error message if an end user enters in a date which contains a 2 digit calendar year format?

Answer (score 0):

First of all `p:calendar` is the old date component, and is deprecated (see https://primefaces.github.io/primefaces/10_0_0/#/../migrationguide/10_0_0). Please switch to `p:datePicker`.

In PrimeFaces 10, the `mask` attribute was introduced to `p:datePicker`, so you can use:

```html
<p:datePicker mask="99/99/9999" .../>
```

This will prevent users from entering a two digit year, so no error message is needed. It uses the same library as the `p:inputMask` does, which is https://github.com/RobinHerbots/Inputmask

See also:

- https://primefaces.github.io/primefaces/10_0_0/#/core/globalattributes

Comment: Jasper - which file (from the files I listed above) would I place this ```<p:datePicker mask="'/>```? Should it be inside ```input.xhtml```? Thank you so much for responding and also for letting me know that ```<p:calendar>``` tag is deprecated! Also, how could I setup the error message? Does this ```mask``` have a default error message or something that I can customize?

Comment: With the mask you are not able to create the error, so no message is needed IMO. Finding `p:calendar` and replacing it with `p:datePicker` will usually do when it comes to migrating.

Comment: this works but doesn't seem to let me pick different years other than 2021? If I type in 2025, it defaults to 2021.

Comment: What if I needed to pick a previous year using DatePicker?

Comment: Typing 2025 works for me. Use `yearNavigator="true"` to select years.

Comment: Can you point to documentation where I can read about ```yearNavigator="true"```? Is this for inputting into the text field or the calendar widget that pops up?

Comment: https://primefaces.github.io/primefaces/10_0_0/#/components/datepicker

Comment: The documentation states that this is for the calendar widget? I'll include it in.

Comment: Did this answer your question?